# Can't properly retrieve the time of an article from an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, web, rss, rss-reader

I have the next problem. I use some php code to read a xml file and post the link of the articles on my webpage. When I created the page in offline mode and tested it on localhost the time was ok, but now, when I made my webpage online, the time is wrong. I contacted the hosting company and they showed me that the server time is ok. So what can be the problem? I'll let some of my code here so maybe someone can figure it out:
First, this is how I load the xml files

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
        $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath("//item[position()<=30]"));
```

And this is where I print the date and time:

```
foreach($entries as $entry){...
<p ><?= strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p', strtotime($entry->pubDate)) ?></p>
...}
```

So what can be the problem? I don't think that is the code's fault, since on the localhost it prints everything ok. The xml file is ok, I checked the time it gives. And as I said, the hosting company told me the server time is ok.

Thank you all!

Comment: `they showed me that the server time is ok.` define "ok" please.

Comment: It depends on the locale timezone settings. so please take a look at the `setlocale` php function!

Comment: I tried setlocale. Still the same. After I checked again I saw that the problem is only with the articles from two websites. I verified their xml files but the time is correct for the articles. I'll leave here links for their feeds: http://www.stiripesurse.ro/rss/stiri.xml and https://www.dcnews.ro/rss/stiri.xml. So only these two website give me the time wrong, even tho I see in the files that the pubDate is correct. Why is it printed wrong on my website? And why only for these two websites? Thanks.